# Back end menu administration in Symfony2 (with Sonata admin bundle)

Tags: symfony, menu, drag-and-drop, sonata, knpmenubundle

I'm learning Symfony2 and I'm trying to "cover" all featured that may be needed for making web site/application. Menus are one of them. So I've installed Symfony2 and Sonata admin bundle.

On the Net I've found that "Knp Menu Bundle" is the most used menu bundle for Symfony2. However, by reading it's documentation I've discovered that it provides only functionality for rendering menu and defining menu items from code. Coming from CMS world this solution looks only partial to me.

What's the best solution for having standard menu functionality, like in CMSes (WordPress, Drupal, name it)? The solution that will allow admin to edit menu tree "visual way" from back-end, re-arrange menu items with drag & drop and similar standard features for any modern CMS. The solution that will work with Sonata or some other admin bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer I've found so far can be seen at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418196/Editing-Tree-Structures-in-Symfony

It uses "Nested tree" Doctrinte extension and it give one solution how nested tree structures like menus can be handled from Sonata admin. Too bad there is no better (out of box) solution for such a common thing as Menu tree.